# Pattern for React when you optionally animate certain components

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, reactjs

I have a few components that *optionally* animate based on certain state. For example, like mobile apps, if the sidebar is open and you tap a nav item in the sidebar we don't do the sliding animation between panels, but if its closed and you tap a link it slides the panels. "Panels" being pages. The code, right now, looks like:

```
  render: function () {
    var appContent;
    if (this.state.sidebarOpen) {
      appContent = <div className="app-content">
                     <this.props.activeRouteHandler ref="route" />
                   </div>
    }
    else {
      appContent = <CSSTransitionGroup component={React.DOM.div}
                      className="app-content"
                      transitionName="pane-animate">
                     <this.props.activeRouteHandler ref="route" />
                   </CSSTransitionGroup>
    }
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar closeHandler={this.sidebarCloseHandler} ref="sidebar" />
        <div className="inner-wrapper">
          {appContent}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

Having that if/else there for just changing if the section should animate or not seems gross and confusing to other developers when they come in and look at it. Is there a better pattern to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

Uses JSX spreads from React v0.12.

```
var CSSTransitionIf = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    if (this.props.test) {
      return <CSSTransitionGroup {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</CSSTransitionGroup>
    }
    else {
      var component = this.props.component
      return <component className={this.props.className}>{this.props.children}</component>
    }
  }
})

//...

  render: function () {
    return <div className="wrapper">
      <Sidebar closeHandler={this.sidebarCloseHandler} ref="sidebar" />
      <div className="inner-wrapper">
        <CSSTransitionIf test={!this.state.sidebarOpen} component={React.DOM.div}
           className="app-content"
           transitionName="pane-animate">
          <this.props.activeRouteHandler ref="route" />
        </CSSTransitionIf>            
      </div>
    </div>
  },

// ...
```

Comment: Im not on 12 yet. Just tried to upgrade and see how hard and everything blew up. I think I can take your concept tho to work in v11